# How to implement Layered/3-tier architecture in PHP?

Tags: php, asp.net-mvc, n-tier-architecture, 3-tier

There are some questions like this around. But they couldn't help me.

I am developing a site for "Social book reading". I am supposed to develop it in Layered architecture (Presentation, Business, Data access). I want to make this site and architecture in PHP, is this possible?
One answer to the question
[How to build n-layered web architecture with PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2539522/how-to-build-n-layered-web-architecture-with-php) says that Zend Frame is best and allows us do implement it in PHP.
Should I be going with it? or anyone believe that other language or platform such as ASP.Net can be a better approach rather than PHP.

Please suggest me the best and easy way to implement it (include tutorial link if possible). My site is not complex, it is a simple project. Thanks

Comment: "It is a simple project" - excellent! That means you can [go forth and try](http://whathaveyoutried.com) in whatever platform that you have core expertise in.

Comment: @EdSF I have limited time, its a semester project. I am not a experienced guy and doing experiment at this time is not an option. I have to go with something that offers my requirements.

Comment: for that, you need to design the folder structure first. this will make you have a good view on the project. take a look at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23555005/php-3-tier-architecture-folder-structure

Comment: looks good, i am using codeigniter